# SOLVED: geoserver.catalog.FailedRequestError: Failed to load coverage information:Failed to create reader from file

Tags: python, geoserver

I have the error

```
geoserver.catalog.FailedRequestError: Failed to load coverage information:Failed to create reader from file:/home/tomcat/data/GaiaGisDataDir/MOSAIC_DATA_DIR/id1626s011002r000-europe/ and hints null
```

from this piece of code.

```
from geoserver.catalog import Catalog, FailedRequestError
from sys import argv


GEOSERVER_SERVER = argv[1]
GEOSERVER_USERNAME = argv[2]
GEOSERVER_PASSWORD = argv[3]



cat = Catalog(GEOSERVER_SERVER, username=GEOSERVER_USERNAME, password=GEOSERVER_PASSWORD)
all_stores = cat.get_stores()
for s in all_stores:
       coverages = cat.mosaic_coverages(s)
       print coverages
       all_granules = cat.list_granules(coverages['coverages']['coverage'][0]['name'],s)
       print all_granules
```

What I wrong?

The directory /home/tomcat/data/GaiaGisDataDir/MOSAIC_DATA_DIR/id1626s011002r000-europe is

```
drwxrwxr-x   3 tomcat    tomcat  16384 Jul 31  2017 ./
drwxr-xr-x 614 tomcat    tomcat  45056 Jan 12 09:07 ../
-rw-rw-r--   1 tomcat    tomcat    345 May 27  2016 datastore.properties
-rw-rw-r--   1 tomcat    tomcat    231 May 27  2016 indexer.properties
drwxrwxr-x   6 tomcat    tomcat   4096 Nov  3  2016 .svn/
-rw-rw-r--   1 tomcat    tomcat     23 May 27  2016 timeregex.properties
-rw-rw-rw-   1 eumetflow tomcat 113094 Jan 10 17:43 wind_p011002_BL_4326_id1626s011002r000-europe_20190110T144300.gaiag.tif
-rw-rw-rw-   1 eumetflow tomcat 113666 Jan 10 17:43 wind_p011002_BL_4326_id1626s011002r000-europe_20190110T144600.gaiag.tif
-rw-rw-rw-   1 eumetflow tomcat 115606 Jan 10 19:23 wind_p011002_BL_4326_id1626s011002r000-europe_20190110T162200.gaiag.tif
```

Comment: what's in the directory? does tomcat have permission to write there? does it work from the GUI?

Comment: yes it's work from the GUI and tomcat has permission to write

Comment: Please check the GeoServer logs and share the full stack trace found there (with all "Caused by" elements, down to the end).

Answer (score 1):

Solved, it was a network configuration error.